# dataweave mapping when otherwise

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio

`Input:-

```
{"id":
{
 "items" : [
{
"merchant_ref": "icici",
"transaction_tag": "sdfhisdb",
"transaction_type": "balance_inquiry",
"method": "valuelink",
"order_number": "123",
"amount": "1000",
"currency_code": "CAD",
"token": {
  "token_type": "",
  "token_data": {
    "type": "",
    "value": "",
    "cardholder_name": "",
    "exp_date": ""
  }
},
{
"merchant_ref": "icici",
"transaction_tag": "sdfhisdb",
"transaction_type": "balance_inquiry",
"method": "valuelink",
"order_number": "123",
"amount": "2000",
"currency_code": "",
"token": {
  "token_type": "",
  "token_data": {
    "type": "",
    "value": "",
    "cardholder_name": "",
    "exp_date": ""
  }
},  
{
"merchant_ref": "icici",
"transaction_tag": "sdfhisdb",
"transaction_type": "authorize",
"method": "token",
"order_number": "123",
"amount": "3000",
"currency_code": "",
"token": {
  "token_type": "",
  "token_data": {
    "type": "",
    "value": "",
    "cardholder_name": "",
    "exp_date": ""
  }
}
```

]
}
}`

Output:- without any Null B, because I need to do to another mapping on the basis of this output with no Null B

```html
<A>
  <B>
    <merchant_ref>icici</merchant_ref>
    <transaction_tag>sdfhisdb</transaction_tag>
    <transaction_type>balance_inquiry</transaction_type>
    <method>valuelink</method>
    <order_number>123</order_number>
    <amount>1000</amount>
    <currency_code>CAD</currency_code>
    <token>
      <token_type></token_type>
      <token_data>
        <type></type>
        <value></value>
        <cardholder_name></cardholder_name>
        <exp_date></exp_date>
      </token_data>
    </token>
  </B>
  <B>
    <merchant_ref>icici</merchant_ref>
    <transaction_tag>sdfhisdb</transaction_tag>
    <transaction_type>balance_inquiry</transaction_type>
    <method>valuelink</method>
    <order_number>123</order_number>
    <amount>2000</amount>
    <currency_code></currency_code>
    <token>
      <token_type></token_type>
      <token_data>
        <type></type>
        <value></value>
        <cardholder_name></cardholder_name>
        <exp_date></exp_date>
      </token_data>
    </token>
  </B>
</A>
```

rying to check the content of xml using the below dataweave but getting output as null B like  Please suggest how to avoid this. as I need to do another point to point mapping from xml to xml for each element but that Mapping is creating an extra map where B is null also.

Please suggest how to avoid this

```html
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---

A: payload.id.*items mapObject
{
 
       B:$  when $.method=="valuelink"      
      
      otherwise {
       
      }
     }
```

Comment: can you add a sample input payload and the output that you want to achieve?

Comment: updated the question, the thing is I have to do another mapping on basis of the the above output like Inquiry: payload.A.*B mapObject (( nd, key ) -> {
 balanceInquiry:
       {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below should work. Note that B:$ is encapsulated by () which means, include this property in output only if 'when' condition is true.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    A: payload.A.*B mapObject {
        (B:$) when $.method == 'valuelink'
    }
}
```